# nServiceBus saga nHibernate

Tags: nservicebus

I'm new to nServiceBus.

nServiceBus version: **2.6.0.1505**

I want to persist saga in database.
Why this doesn't work:

```
public class MessageEndpoint : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server, IWantCustomInitialization
{
    public void Init()
    {
        Configure.With().DefaultBuilder().Sagas().NHibernateSagaPersister();
    }
}
```

It throws an error:

> Exception occurred in
>   Topshelf.Internal.ServiceController`1[[NServiceBus.Host.Internal.GenericHost,
>   NServiceBus.Host, Version=2.6.0.1505, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226c]] during state Initial while handling
>   OnStart

Is it possible to configure an endpoint in this way in this version of nServiceBus?

**Edit:**

Endpoint configuration changed to:

```
public class MessageEndpoint : IConfigureThisEndpoint, 
    AsA_Server, 
    IWantCustomInitialization
{
    public void Init()
    {
        Configure.With()
            .DefaultBuilder()
            .XmlSerializer()
            .Sagas()
            .NHibernateSagaPersister();
    }
}
```

Saga executes, but an exception is thrown:

> 2012-07-30 16:36:12,229 [Worker.5] INFO 
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus [(null)]  <(null)> - Received message
>   Messages.StartCmd, Messages, Version=1.0.0.0, Cultu re=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null with ID 0adbb2fd-4a7d-4fa2-ae09-70bbcbbc8241\206 9
>   from sender MyWebClient@USER-PC 2012-07-30 16:36:12,232 [Worker.5]
>   INFO  NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus [(null)]  <(null)> - Can't
>   impersonate because no windows identity specified in incoming message.
>   This is common in interop scenarios.
>
> 2012-07-30 16:36:12,294 [Worker.5] WARN 
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Msmq.Msmq Transport [(null)] <(null)> -
>   Failed raising 'transport message received' event for message with
>   ID=0adbb2fd-4a7d-4fa2-ae09-70bbcbbc8241\2069
>   Spring.Objects.Factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating
>   object wit h name 'NServiceBus.Sagas.Impl.SagaMessageHandler' :
>   Unsatisfied dependency expr essed through object property 'Persister':
>   There are 2 objects of Type [NService Bus.Saga.ISagaPersister] for
>   autowire by type, when there should have been just 1 to be able to
>   autowire property 'Persister' of object 'NServiceBus.Sagas.Impl.
>   SagaMessageHandler'.    at
>   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.Autowi
>   reByType(String name, RootObjectDefinition definition, IObjectWrapper
>   wrapper, M utablePropertyValues properties)    at
>   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.Popula
>   teObject(String name, RootObjectDefinition definition, IObjectWrapper
>   wrapper)    at
>   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.Config
>   ureObject(String name, RootObjectDefinition definition, IObjectWrapper
>   wrapper)    at
>   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.Instan
>   tiateObject(String name, RootObjectDefinition definition, Object[]
>   arguments, Bo olean allowEagerCaching, Boolean suppressConfigure)
>   at
>   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractObjectFactory.GetObjectInternal(Str
>   ing name, Type requiredType, Object[] arguments, Boolean
>   suppressConfigure)    at
>   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractObjectFactory.GetObject(String
>   name )    at
>   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.DefaultListableObjectFactory.GetObjectsOfTy
>   pe(Type type, Boolean includePrototypes, Boolean
>   includeFactoryObjects)    at
>   Spring.Context.Support.AbstractApplicationContext.GetObjectsOfType(Type
>   ty pe, Boolean includePrototypes, Boolean includeFactoryObjects)    at
>   NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.Spring.SpringObjectBuilder.NServiceBus.ObjectBui
>   lder.Common.IContainer.Build(Type typeToBuild)    at
>   NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.Common.CommonObjectBuilder.NServiceBus.ObjectBui
>   lder.IBuilder.BuildAndDispatch(Type typeToBuild, Action`1 action)
>   at
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.DispatchMessageToHandlersBasedOnType(IMessa
>   ge toHandle, Type messageType)    at
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.HandleMessage(TransportMessage m)    at
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.TransportMessageReceived(Object sender,
>   Tra nsportMessageReceivedEventArgs e)    at
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Msmq.MsmqTransport.OnTransportMessageReceive
>   d(TransportMessage msg)

Looks like this is the reason why it fails:

> There are 2 objects of Type [NService Bus.Saga.ISagaPersister] for
>   autowire by type, when there should have been just 1 to be able to
>   autowire property 'Persister' of object 'NServiceBus.Sagas.Impl.
>   SagaMessageHandler'

Comment: Did you check out the Saga example that ships with NSB?  Do you have the Saga configuration set?

Comment: I have NHibernateSagaPersisterConfig section in config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to persist saga using NHibernate.

Endpoint configuration (doesn't require IWantCustomInitialization):

```
public class MessageEndpoint : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server
{
}
```

The trick is to tell the host to use Production profile - http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/nservicebus-host/profiles

[image]